# How can I make program1 is getting input from promram2 and program2 is getting input from terminal at the same time?

Tags: c, io, terminal, redirect

I have a homework. I have to redirect my program input to another of my program wich waits command from terminal:

```
./mycat | ./mymore
```

The problem is when I run my program like above, "mymore" can not get commands from terminal. Can anyone tell me how can I make "mymore" getting input from termial and "mycat" from "mymore" in the sane time?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I really understood your question but if you do

```
./mymore | ./mycat
```

then mymore gets its input from the standard input (the terminal) and mycat will gets its input from mymore's output.